# Binary resources embedded in .exe and memory management when loaded

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I'm working in a small C program and I need to embed binary data into an exe file. The method I'm using is converting that binary data into a char[] array... but I'm not including directly that array as a global variable; instead, I copy that array inside a function (LoadResource) that dynamically creates an array on heap, where I copy my original data. That's what I mean:

```
char *dataPntr;

void LoadResource()
{
    char data[2048] = {/*my binary data */};

    dataPntr = malloc(2048);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) dataPntr [i] = data[i];
}
```

That way, if my understanding is correct, when calling LoadResource() data[] will be placed in stack, copied to heap and finally data[] will be automatically deallocated from stack; heap copy should be manually deallocated with free().

I'm doing it this way because the resource is only used in some situations, not always... and I prefer to avoid a large global variable.

My questions:

When running the program, is data[] array placed somewhere in memory? text segment maybe? or is it just loaded into stack when calling LoadResource()?

Is my solution the proper one (in terms of memory management) or would it be better to just declare a global data array?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `dataPntr` mis-spelt as `gloablPntr` in the loop.

Comment: I’m not sure I get why you do it this way. Do you change the binary data? If not, then a global `const` would work just fine – and it would not make your program any larger, either on disk or in memory, while your code makes the memory footprint larger when the program actually uses the data. And that extra memory will not be shared between processes running the same executable, unlike a `const` global, which would.

Comment: The data[] is allocated on the stack at run time i.e when the function LoadResource is called. Am not sure if this is what you were asking.

Comment: If you don't really need dynamic allocation you could place a "const char data[] = { ... }" in file scope. Compile it to something like data.o and other files that need access to it can write "extern const char data[]". This way there is no need to load anything because it happens on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with @cdarke in general, it sounds to me that you are creating a constant array (i. e. is never modified at run-time). If this is true, I would not hesitate to make it a global `const` array. Most compilers will simply place the array in text memory at link time and there will not be any run-time overhead for initialization.

If, on the other hand, you need to modify the data at run-time, I'd follow @cdarke's example, except to make your `data` array `static const`. This way, again, most compilers will place the preinitialized array in the text segment and you will avoid the run-time overhead for initializing the `data` array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DoxyLover! I've been doing some tests and I've seen that, using gcc, if data is defined as const, it is placed in text memory. If data is defined as static but no const it is placed in data segment. I also noted some weird behaviour depending on DATA_SIZE, when not being a multiple of 8, probably related to memory alignment... Thanks again for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is a good idea to avoid global variables.  I won't say you *never* need them, but they can be a pain to debug.  The problem is that it can be difficult to follow who changed it last.  And if you ever do any multi-threading then you will never want to see a global again!

I include your `char *dataPntr` in those comments - why is that global?  It might be better to return the pointer instead.

Not sure why you are using an array on the stack (`data`), my guess is so that you can use the `{...}` initialisation syntax.  Can you avoid that?  It might not be a big deal, 2k is not a large overhead, but maybe it might grow?

Personally I would copy the data using `memcpy()`

You have a couple of "magic numbers" in your code, 2048 and 2018.  Maybe one is a typo?  To avoid this kind of issue, most will use a pre-processor macro.  For example:

```
#include <string.h>      /* for memcpy() */

#define DATA_SIZE 2048

char * LoadResource(void)
{
    char data[DATA_SIZE] = {/*my binary data */};

    char * dataPntr = malloc(DATA_SIZE);

    if (dataPntr) 
        memcpy(dataPntr, data, DATA_SIZE);

    return dataPntr;
}
```

By the way, notice the prototype for `LoadResource` as `void`.  In C (not C++) an empty parameter list means no parameter *checking*, not no parameters.  Also note that I check the returned value from `malloc`.  This means that the function will return `NULL` on error.

Another strategy might be to make the `data` array `static` instead, however exactly when that gets initialised is compiler dependant, and you might find that you incur the memory overhead even if you don't use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Thanks for pointing all those ways to improve my code! :D Excuse me for my typos...

Comment: DATA_SIZE is variable and can be quite big (around 700Kb), I already take care of it to avoid a stack overflow. About making data array static, I thought it was the same as making it global (it was allocated at runtime). Along with my first question, is data array placed somewhere in memory before calling LoadResource()? Thanks again for your answers!

Comment: Making the array `static` means that it is only visible within the current block, or compilation unit (source file) if global.  `static` within a function is only guaranteed to initialise it before the first function call, so (in theory) if the function is never called then it might not be initialised, except the compiler might choose to initialise it earlier.